# ImageNet Pre-Trained Weights for Google Tensorflow ResNet Implementations

Tags: tensorflow, resnet, imagenet

Are there any pre-trained models for the implementation of resnet in tensorflow provided by Google? I have looked around and have not been able to find anything yet.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet